# rank hot encoding python3

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I want to process a pandas dataframe with rank-hot encoding instead of one-hot encoding.

For example take this pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,2],[2,2]], columns=['colA', 'colB'])
print(df)
>>  colA  colB
0     1     2
1     3     0
2     2     3
```

How it should look in the end:

```
print(df)
>> colA_0  colA_1  colA_2  colA_3  colB_0  colB_1  colB_2  colB_3
0    1       1       0       0       1        1       1      0
1    1       1       1       1       1        0       0      0
2    1       1       1       0       1        1       1      1
```

This worked on small dataFrames:

```
def rankHotEncode(row):
    newFeatures = {}
    for i, v in row.iteritems():
        for k in range(MULTIPLYFEATURES):
            newFeatures[i + repr(k)] = 1 if v >= k else 0
    return pd.Series(newFeatures)

df.apply(rankHotEncode, axis=1)
```

The solution should not be hardcoded and efficient for order ~100.000 rows.
How can I improve the provided solution to make it more efficient or what is the best way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Requirements are nice, but doing don't really constitute a valid programming question. Also, why are you using pandas for this?

Comment: @MadPhysicist the question got updated with a not efficient solution and so far pandas was the best way to work with my data because of the built-in functions.

Comment: Thanks. Close vote removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use scikit-learn [`oneHotEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) with [`numpy.cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html). While it involves some copies, it is quite efficient as it does not deal with the matrix row by row. Here is a sample code using it.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,0],[2,3]], columns=['colA', 'colB'])
print(df)

n_values = df.max().values + 1
enc = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, n_values=n_values, dtype=int)
enc.fit(df) 

encoded_columns = [
    '{}_{}'.format(col_name, i)
    for col_name, n_value in zip(df.columns, n_values)
    for i in range(n_value)
]

one_hot = enc.transform(df)
rank_hot = np.zeros_like(one_hot)

for col_start, col_end in zip(enc.feature_indices_[:-1], enc.feature_indices_[1:]):
    one_hot_col_reversed = one_hot[:, col_start: col_end][:, ::-1]
    rank_hot[:, col_start: col_end] = np.cumsum(one_hot_col_reversed, axis=1)[:, ::-1]

encoded_df = pd.DataFrame(rank_hot, columns=encoded_columns)
```

It outputs for your example

```
print(encoded_df)
>>    colA_0  colA_1  colA_2  colA_3  colB_0  colB_1  colB_2  colB_3
0       1       1       0       0       1       1       1       0
1       1       1       1       1       1       0       0       0
2       1       1       1       0       1       1       1       1
```